# Load keras model from text file

Tags: python, json, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have my model layers stored in a text file as shown below:

```
{

"model" : "Sequential",

"layers": [

{
    "L1": "Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid', data_format='channels_last', dilation_rate=None, activation='relu', use_bias=True, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros', kernel_regularizer=None, bias_regularizer=None, activity_regularizer=None, kernel_constraint=None, bias_constraint=None, input_shape=(28,28,1))",

    "L2": "Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid', data_format='channels_last', dilation_rate=None, activation='relu', use_bias=True, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros', kernel_regularizer=None, bias_regularizer=None, activity_regularizer=None, kernel_constraint=None, bias_constraint=None)" ,

    "L3": "Flatten()",

    "L4": "Dense(10, activation='softmax', use_bias=True, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros', kernel_regularizer=None, bias_regularizer=None, activity_regularizer=None, kernel_constraint=None, bias_constraint=None)"
}
   ]

}
```

I am trying to load the model in python console like this:

```
with open('model.txt','r') as fb:
    con = json.load(fb, object_pairs_hook=ordereddict.OrderedDict)
from keras.models import Sequential
model = Sequential()
model.add(con['layers'][0]['L1'])
```

But it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ashutosh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 132, in add
    'Found: ' + str(layer))

TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid', data_format='channels_last', dilation_rate=None, activation='relu', use_bias=True, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros', kernel_regularizer=None, bias_regularizer=None, activity_regularizer=None, kernel_constraint=None, bias_constraint=None)
```

What should I do to load the Conv2D layer from text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`con['layers'][0]['L1']` is a string.

Consider executing it using `eval`

```
model.add(eval(con['layers'][0]['L1']))
```